# Library to detect IDN domain from a string?

Tags: url, uri, idn

IM/Email type scenario:

User types whatever they want and sends it to their buddy. If they enter a URL, I want to make it clickable for the recipient. This means we need to identify a sequence of characters within the string is a valid URI and make a hyperlink out of it.

Is there a library to help parse the user input and detect if the user types an internationalized domain name as part of a string?

example:

*hey dude this Russian McDonald's site макдональдс.рф is cool - check it out!*

Note I am not talking about parsing the URI or doing punycode/Unicode conversions - I need to be able to identify this as a URI first before doing any of that...